# Find the norms of the linear operator $Af(x) =f(x^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory

Find the 1-norms of the linear operator $Af(x) =f(x^2)$ if:

a) $A: C[0,1] \rightarrow C[0,1]$

b) $A: C[-1,1] \rightarrow C[0,1]$

c) $A: L^1(0,1) \rightarrow L^2(0,1)$

I honestly have no idea how to do this.
For part a, my guess is: 
$\|Af\|= \|f(x^2)\| \leq \|f(x)\| \forall f \in C[0,1] $? then I don't know what to do from here.

For part b, I think you get the same inequality except here its $\forall f \in C[-1,1]$, but again I don't know how to conclude this.

For part c, we have $\|Af(x)\|_1 \leq \|f(x^2)\|_1$

I keep seeing examples online where they just let be equal to some value such as $f \equiv 1 $ in order to show $\|A\| \geq$ whatever bound we get from above, but I don't understand why that's ok or if I can do the same here.

EDIT: I understand parts a and b, but I'm still confused on part c

Comment: Which norm are you using in $C\bigl([0,1]\bigr)$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The max norm

Comment: you should add `1-` after "Find the ". I would edit it for you. But stackexchange somehow thinks edits on math questions need to have minimal character length.

Comment: @Argyll Changed! Thank you

Comment: How is A linear? Are you sure you've copied the problem correctly?

Comment: @Acccumulation yes.  the only thing different is it was originally "find the norms" not "find the 1-norms"

Comment: Was just about to type up my answer (after complaining about the minimum character limit on meta). And you seem to have already received one.

Comment: @Argyll Thank you, but I'm honestly still confused on what to do for part c so I would appreciate an answer that covers that

Comment: I'll need to come back later. (if it hasn't been answered yet.)

Comment: @Argyll Thank you. I'd appreciate it

Comment: I am back. In a) and b), do you mean continuous functions that map from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ or just domain is $[0,1]$?

Comment: Also, for c), are we using the typical p norms in the $L_p$ spaces?

Comment: @VinnyChase: are you sure you want what Argyll said? You want $\|\cdot\|_1$ in the three cases?

Comment: @MartinArgerami: see my latest comments. $1$-norm doesn't seem to make c) solvable. But even with $L_p$ norms, I am not entirely convinced that $f(x)$ absolutely integrable implies $f(x^2)$ square integrable. I recommended the edit because his later examples use $1$-norm. Something is missing here.

Answer (score 1):

For a) and b), the answer is $1$. It is clear that $\|Af\|\leqslant\|f\|$ and, if you take $f=1$, you get that $\|Af\|=\|f\|=1$.

Comment: But why can you just take f=1?

Comment: because that's one of the only two norm-1 constant functions?

Comment: @VinnyChase I proved that $\|A\|\geqslant1$. So, if I find a function $f$ such that $\|f\|=\|Af\|=1$, that will prove that $\|A\|=1$. And it turns out that if you take $f=1$, then, indeed, $\|f\|=\|Af\|=1$.

Comment: Thank you.  What about for c?

Comment: @VinnyChase I don't even understand why is it that $Af\in L^2(0,1)$.

Comment: Any explanation for why A is being referred to as a "linear operator"?

Comment: @Acccumulation Perhaps because it is a linear operator.

Comment: How so? If f: x->x, then A(2f) = 4A(f)

Comment: @Acccumulation: not true. $A(2f)=2Af$. Look closer at the definition of $A$